# How do I turn this conditional logic into a ternary expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, expression, conditional-statements, ternary

Here is small little jquery plugin that checks if the element passed in is an input element and if it is empty:

```
$.fn.inputIsEmpty = function() {
    if (!this.is('input:text')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0;
    }
};
```

The above logic works. So I tried turning this into a sweetened ternary expression:

```
$.fn.inputIsEmpty = function() {
    this.is('input:text') ? $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0 : false;
};
```

But it just returns undefined - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Toooooooooo localised

Comment: This is less readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of operator short circuiting:

```
return this.is('input:text') && $.trim(this.val()).length === 0;
```

If `this.is('input:text')` is `false`, the second part won't need to be evaluated, as `false && any boolean` will be `false` regardless of the other boolean's value. It acts like your `if` statement.

Comment: +1 , This is the best solution. I just hurried my answer through :P

Comment: love this - just learnt something new today - thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
$.fn.inputIsEmpty = function() {
   return (this.is('input:text') ? ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) : false);
};
```

Comment: awesome - this works - so this is where the return keyword goes